# Find the probability of at least one lobster being caught in the afternoon given that more lobsters were caught in the morning.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am solving the following problem from Sheldon Ross:
Lobsters are caught in morning and afternoon sessions. The number of lobsters that can be caught in each session are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, each with probability 1/6. Find the probability of at least one lobster being caught in the afternoon given that more lobsters were caught in the morning.

I can solve it using conditionals and looking at all the possibilities. I would like to use random variables instead. Denote X as the amount of fish caught in the afternoon and Y as the amount of fish caught in the morning. Then the problem is asking for
$$P(X\geq 1|Y> X)=\frac{P(X\geq1,Y> X)}{P(Y>X)}$$
Is there any way to compute the above without resorting to look at all the cases?

Thanks.

Comment: There is missing information. What do the morning and afternoon catches have to do with each other?

Comment: @EthanBolker I'd guess they are independent but I agree that this should be stated.

Comment: @EthanBolker $X,Y$ are independent (I assume, otherwise the problem is impossible). Note that $X,Y-X$ are not independent.

Comment: Should there be information about the amount of morning and afternoon sessions? If they are not equal then the problem doesn't make sense. For example of there are double the amount of sessions in the morning than in the afternoon, the condition "given that more lobsters were caught in the morning" doesn't particularly influence the requested probability.

Comment: Also, the more afternoon sessions there are, the more the probability "at least one lobster being caught in the afternoon" increases. So the question is missing information as it is worded now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(Y<X) + P(Y=X)+P(Y>X)=1 $$
since $P(Y=X)=\frac 16$  and $P(Y<X) =P(Y>X)$

We must have $P(Y>X)=\frac 5{12}$

$$P(X=0, Y>X) + P(X\ge1, Y>X)= P(Y>X)$$

$$P(X=0, Y>X)= \frac 5{36}\implies P(X\ge1, Y>X)=\frac 5{18}$$

So...
$$P(X\ge 1|Y>X) = \frac 23$$